# Specifying a custom remote-repo in a cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to work on a project in a cabal sandbox. But instead of using the same `remote-repo` as my non-sandboxed code (i.e., Hackage), I'd like to point to a different remote repo. I tried creating a `cabal.config` file in the project directory with a `remote-repo` line, but it seemed to have no effect; running `cabal update` after that indicated that Hackage was being downloaded, but not my custom repo.

Is this use case supported, and if so, how do I achieve it?

Comment: I think you need to name the file `cabal.sandbox.config`.

Comment: The top of that file says: -- This is a Cabal package environment file.
-- THIS FILE IS AUTO-GENERATED. DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY.
-- Please create a 'cabal.config' file in the same directory
-- if you want to change the default settings for this sandbox.

Comment: Adding a `remote-repo` line to a cabal.config only sets the repository as a [secondary option](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1488) (when the first one is offline): it's a list rather than a single field.  Don't know if that feature exists in Cabal.  *Maybe reopen that issue or create a feature request?*

Comment: @RudyMatela I don't see the "secondary option" implication in that issue, sorry. To be clear, adding a second remote-repo to the main cabal config file works as I'd expect (both repos are used simultaneously).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact a Cabal bug, I've [opened a Github issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1884) about it.